# Problem involving Energy Method and Non-conservative Forces

Tags: friction, potential-energy, spring

I've got a problem in my physics I class that's got me stuck at the moment. A box is placed onto an angled plane so that it compresses a spring. When released, how far up the plane does the box go?

- k = 300N/m
- Spring compressed = 0.35 meters
- Mass of box = 2 kg
- Friction coeffecient between mass and plane = 0.25
- Angle of plane = 25 degrees

So far I've solved that the distance traveled up the plane should be 1.44 meters, but when I use interactive physics (a program my university supplies for physics labs), I get an answer of 1.27 meters. I've tried changing my approach a few times and have either wound up with a completely different answer or very close to 1.44 meters.

To solve it, I had

- (Spring Potential Energy) - (Work of Friction) = (Gravitational Potential Energy)

so that

- 0.5(300)(0.35^2) - 4.44*s = 19.6(s*sin 25 degrees)

From there:

- 18.375 = 8.28s + 4.44s

That leaves s at around 1.4445 meters. Did I get the right answer? Or is the simulation software correct?

Edit: Oh, and I forgot to mention, the mass is NOT connected to the spring.

Comment: Hi OSG. Your question falls afoul of [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [the check my workpolicy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic), though I appreciate your really asking about the software not your work. For what it's worth I redid the calculation and get the same answer as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks correct.  I didn't check your arithmetic, but I suspect that you got the right answer and that the issue here is that your expectations of Interactive Physics are not realistic.

Interactive Physics is a simplified educational version of the Computer Aided Engineering program called Adams.  This program is intended to produce results which duplicate reality.  Thus you can set the elasticity of your objects, their surface texture, their density, and so on.  The program does not assume that the box stays on the ramp.  The normal force modeled by the program probably oscillates wildly as the box skitters off the ramp surface.  With the appropriate attention to detail, the program can be used to get reliable results, but there are many subtle considerations in setting up a model to get accurate, numerically converged results.  Long story short, the model you set up was different from the problem you solved, so the results were also different.